# Differential communication, VCC and GND recovery

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential

modern MCUs are consuming so little power that I started thinking about using only two differential data transmission lines for sending not only data but power also. I made a simple schematic below of the idea. I am sure it is nothing new, but how to do this properly? I would like to achieve proper 5V TLL output range on the data line (opamp output). If you would like to play with it in the online simulator here is [the link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0wA4BsqBMAWBBOBAdhwGYsLcR18QkFIAoAGRAFox0RzJ3zusvXhABmAQwA2AZwCmdKIwCSA7pBzgwWVeqHR6jAO4rSpLvx4KjYImbXgbIHHEshcvE1zePnTACb2uJ15BVG5MVxBfGXEAVwkAF0Z-EMd%20a0DnLSjYhKTXSFCyLS8giOyxOMTkp29ggrDQrOiK3KMUotciLQ6mNvrTRq6GhUFaLCGBzu7%20XXhICBxoLFRSHCIweaITVBx8dTBDDS1SOzAcdRP1LEOzi9Mj7nvrtpqPV1RQt96p4fHioe%20f1Sxx2wJcQKBpFBQKYTlobwsHQsEBgXDYiywYGIZEg6EgDDWaGQkCwpA2cwp8C0TAATu9PvcEfdhHNGHTlp87Ai7Cz4IcoVcPtxoQDDh0kaCemL%20ECcOgrkNnmDxfKwdcALKOVWI1DuQRQVx6G4OS707QuMCaR5mY7M-ki6b-anS476uUXfVKgXcBAg9RSowcG3CYOufmuvXm763a2uV52qznc3pKM3UPmfXfd3K3VgrOq2W5mGMAD2GnABrhtA2xPg%20BsCHQWCQwXLpEYQA).

[image]

Comment: If you want 5.0V at the output of your rectifier, then you're going to have to either start with a higher signal voltage, or use a DC-DC boost converter. Or maybe a small transformer at the input of your rectifier. But 5.0V is so last millennium. Why not go with 3.3V on the remote node?

Comment: 4.6V at supply is absolute fine. The issue is that data output is 1,6V for low, which is a way to high. Any clue how to lower it to expected TTL output levels?

Comment: It would be possible to remove the voltage drop with synchronous rectification.

Comment: @noonespecial: That's an issue with whatever chip you're using as a receiver. You used the term "opamp", and if that's what you're actually using, it may not be up to the job. There are plenty of low-voltage differential line receivers that will output good logic levels.